# Composer - restore deleted file?

Tags: composer-php, yii2

I use composer to manage packages. But I delete one of files from package (I use `composer status -v` to check this).

Is it possible to restore changed/deleted files to it base (installed) state via composer (composer install doing nothing in my case) ?

Thanks.

ps. It's look like there no way to restore separate file from repo, after his been changed/deleted. Of course, it's possible to delete entire vendor dir, and reinstall some package totally.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific about which files you deleted. Were they files from your `vendor` folder?

Comment: yes it is.  I delete from vendors and "composer status -v" report that file was deleted - D  widgets/ActiveForm.php

Comment: And neither `composer install` or `composer update` re-install the dependency?

Comment: I don't consider to update the files. With experimental purposes, I repeatedly del. a file from package, then I run `composer status -v` - composer report to me the file was deleted, but after I ran `composer install` I get issue -   **Nothing to install or update**

Comment: And does it work if you try to manually specify which package you want to install: `php composer install [vendor]/[package_name]` ?

Comment: No. I think the reason, Yii2 uses his own composer extension. It's need to observe.

Comment: If you remove the `/vendor/package_name` folder and run `composer install` afterwards it should reinstall the package.

Answer (score 2):

I edit dependant package source code all the time and run into the issue of my local being out of sync with the remove source.

When things get really sideways and nothing works: delete the package providers dir inside the ./vendor (exp: ./vendor/author-name). Then composer will see the package is missing when running `composer install`. It will re-download the version specified in composer.lock.

If you want the latest version of all the packages when re-installing; `composer update` is what you want.

I also recommend using `-o -vvv` to generate the AuoLoader file and provide verbose output.